# ReadOnly TextBoxes

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

How to select single character from a word in a read-only textbox. I have a read-only text box in my Windows Phone 8 application. When I am selecting text fro the textbox it selects words by words i want to select text character by character. is there any way to to do this?

Comment: What do you mean by "it selects words by words"? Are you trying to do this programmatically? Have you tried using SelectionStart and SelectionLength properties?

Comment: that means cannot select select single character in a word. Such as the letter "L" in "HELLO". It selects whole word. As read-only textboxs have no carets Tap and hold is also not working.

Answer (score 0):

If you only aim to get each character from string, hope following will help.

```
string textToSeparate= "String to seperate";
char[] chArray = textToSeparate.ToCharArray();

foreach (char ch in chArray)
{
    // Here you get each character
}
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. It's not about getting individual characters from a string. If it were, I'd suggest `textToSeperate[intIndex]` rather than building a copy of the string as an array.